# how to passing session values between 2 controllers in ASP MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ActionResult Login in UsersController and in Login Called AterLogin that being in NEWSController.Now, I want read an Session that created in Login.
Login code :

```
public ActionResult Login(Users U)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (NEWSDBContext DB = new NEWSDBContext())
            {
                var v = DB.Userss.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(U.UserName   

                 && a.PassWord.Equals(U.PassWord)).FirstOrDefault();`                                  
                if (v != null)
                {
                    Session["LogedUserID"] = v.UserID.ToString();
                    Session["LogedUserFullname"] = v.Name.ToString() + " " + v.Family.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("AfterLogin","NEWS");
                }


            }
        }

        return View(U);
    }
```

AfterLogin code :

```
  public ActionResult AfterLogin()
    {
        int id = int.Parse(Session["LogedUserID"].ToString());
        NEWS news = db.NEWSs.Find(id);
        return View(news);
    }
```

Comment: So what problems are you having? What are you expecting and what is actually happening?

Comment: I could not see the problem either.